# How do i find the welcome wizard pages id? Innosetup

Tags: plugins, inno-setup

I am using the ITD tools plugin to download a file file over the internet and i need the Wizardpage's id after which i want the download screen. I need the welcome screens id. How can i know this? I searched for this online and couldn't find it. I need this as an argument in my ITD_DownloadAfter() function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use hardcoded IDs but use Inno Setup Constants:

> PageID values for predefined wizard pages:
>
> wpWelcome, wpLicense,
>   wpPassword, wpInfoBefore, wpUserInfo, wpSelectDir, wpSelectComponents,
>   wpSelectProgramGroup, wpSelectTasks, wpReady, wpPreparing,
>   wpInstalling, wpInfoAfter, wpFinished

See the [manual for more info](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=PageID).

Comment: Im gonna post a question in a minute, i want you to check it out.

Comment: That is reason why I wrote: "Do not use hardcoded IDs but use Inno Setup Constants" :)